# How to set data type as longtext in Yii2 migration

Tags: yii2, database-migration

I use following code in order to get desired values of attribute for `bodytext`. Data type should be `longtext()` or `varchar()`. DBMS is MySQL.

With following code `bodytext` will be created as `varchar(255)`. Why?

```
$this->createTable('mail_eingang', [
    'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
    'mail_adresse_absender' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
    'betreff' => $this->string(255),
    'bodytext' => $this->string(), //this will actually set bodytext to varchar(255). It should be longtext() or varchar() !!
    'gelesen' => $this->smallInteger(1)->notNull()->defaultValue(0),
    'angelegt_am' => $this->datetime(),
    'angelegt_von' => $this->integer(11),
    'aktualisiert_am' => $this->datetime(),
    'aktualisiert_von' => $this->integer(11),
    'FOREIGN KEY ([[angelegt_von]]) REFERENCES person ([[id]]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT',
    'FOREIGN KEY ([[aktualisiert_von]]) REFERENCES person ([[id]]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT',
], $tableOptions);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If 64 KB is enough for you, you may use [`text()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait#text()-detail):

```
'bodytext' => $this->text()
```

If you really need a longtext column, you should use something like:

```
'bodytext' => $this->getDb()->getSchema()->createColumnSchemaBuilder('longtext');
```

Or specify type as raw string:

```
'bodytext' => 'LONGTEXT',
```

Comment: All right. Great job, works pretty fine. Thx a lot for this. Gave u reputation points for ur efforts!